# When are set-mouse-position and mouse-position different?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am trying to test if a certain position of an Emacs window is visible thus is neither overlapped by another window nor somehow obscured by decoration facilities.  To this end I set the mouse position to a certain point and then compare the set values to `(mouse-position)`.  However, I get somewhat different values.

How does the actual `(mouse-position)` differ from the set value?
(Provided that mouse is not moved by the user, indeed).

To test it quickly <kbd>C-x C-e</kbd>

```
(list (set-mouse-position (selected-frame) 4 4) (mouse-position))
```

As for `pos-visible-in-window-p`, this does not perform an actual test. To see this

```
 (progn (sleep-for 5) (pos-visible-in-window-p 1))
```

with <kbd>C-u C-x C-e</kbd> and lower, hide the window.  Alas, it still is true.

Comment: IIRC, Emacs can't know that.  It might get to know whether it did *draw* this part of the buffer on the screen, but nowadays with compositing window-managers, applications often have to draw every part of their windows, even if in the end they'll be obscured by something else.

Another way to look at it is: what if it's slightly obscured by a 90% transparent window?  And what about a 10% transparent window?

Comment: @Stefan: At least the method I describe works (mostly). It can detect many anomalies, like some bars that hide the echo area. It's not perfect, though.

Comment: @Stefan: For transparency, it depends. Can you still place the mouse in that place and then "have" the mouse? That's what is relevant here. So transparency alone is not interesting only places where you can actually still do something are taken into account.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that [`pos-visible-in-window-p`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Window-Start-and-End.html) should do what you want.

Note that your expression moves the actual mouse pointer, i.e., it is visible to the user.

Comment: Right, it moves the mouse, actually, I save and restore the original `mouse-pixel-position` around